# Bowl a rectangular quine

Tags: restricted-source, quine, code-bowling

## Code-Bowling Quine Challenge

You must bowl a quine following the rules of code bowling and quines but the source code must be in the shape of a **rectangle** (details specified below)

---

## Quine

Quines returned must be returned via the ways defined in [the standard I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).

---

## Rules

#### Code-Bowling Rules

1. **Character : Byte Ratio**  In Code-Bowling a character-count is
   preferred over a byte-count. The obvious reasoning for this is that
   multi-byte unicode characters (e.g. ) can be used in place of
   single-byte unicode characters to fluff up byte count and will make
   bowling more about who renames the most variables with high-byte
   unicode characters rather than who most strategically creates
   meaningful complex code. (See Useful tools section at end for
   character-counting widget)
2. **Variable/Function/Object Names**  All variable names (or object pointers, function names, etc) should be 1 character long. The only
   acceptable time to use 2-character variables names is after all
   possible 1-character variables have been used. The only acceptable
   time to use 3-character variables names is after all possible
   2-character variables have been used. Etc.
3. **Non-simplified Arithmetic**  All arithmetic should be in simplified form unless there is a justifiable reason for doing otherwise (e.g.
   circumventing penalties defined in the scoring system of the
   challenge (In which case you still must use the smallest possible
   alternative form)). Finding the simplified form of any equation (as
   well as a list of small alternative forms) is easy to do using
   Wolfram|Alpha. (See Useful tools section at end)
4. **Un-used Code**  All code must be used. Meaning the program must fail to always properly complete the task if any individual character (or
   varying set(s) of characters) is/are removed. Naturally, a subset of
   the program should not be able complete the task on its own without
   the rest of the program.
5. **Line-breaks and White-space**  Unless necessary for code function or otherwise specified by the challenge, all line-breaks and
   white-space should be removed from code before scoring by counting
   characters.
6. **Comments**  Comments are not permitted towards character-count, unless somehow utilized by your program/function.

#### Rectangle Rules

Your code must be in the shape of a rectangle, i.e. every line has the same number of characters. Your code must have at least 2 lines, with at least 3 chars on each line.

Also, each line of code must be distinct to a certain threshold. Distinctness is calculated using the Levenshtein distance. The threshold is 85%, meaning the Levenshtein distance between any two lines must be greater than or equal to 0.85*w, where w is the number of characters used in a line of your rectangle.

And for convenience, here is a [Levenshtein distance calculator](https://planetcalc.com/1721/) and a [character length calculator](http://ethproductions.github.io/bytes/?e=chars).

---

## Scoring

This is a [code-bowling](/questions/tagged/code-bowling) variant. The program with the highest number of characters wins!

Comment: Just want to clarify, do all `common rules` apply; and for the rectangle scoring system is the Levenshtein distance threshold for this challenge 85%?

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw yes

Comment: "Meaning the program must fail to always properly complete the task if any individual character (or varying set(s) of characters) is/are removed." Can fail also mean that removing characters prevents the code from being a rectangle?

Comment: Possibly related: Hello world with the shape of hello world

Comment: I'd be disappointed if you couldn't score infinity in the limit on this one (the only difficult part would be creating a checksum operation that can handle having arbitrary subsets of bytes deleted from it).

Comment: @ais523 it would fail un needed bytes

Comment: @DownChristopher: All the bytes are needed because the checksum wouldn't match otherwise, thus causing the code to fail to work. This is a common trick used in "all the bytes must matter" [tag:restricted-source] questions.

Comment: @ais523 It's possible that the checksum part of the code itself could be removed as well. `No subset of the program should be able to complete the task.` Granted I dont know exactly how the check sum code works, need an example to tell

Comment: A trick that would probably work would be to make the checksum executable code, and `eval` it. Removing the checksum would mean that part of the code doesn't run, and thus the program fails. Removing any of the part of the code that gets checksummed would cause the wrong code to run. The only really hard part is designing the checksum in such a way that you can't find a subset of the code that would sum to the same value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Python 3, 89 bytes

```python
a='a=%r;b=%r;p=\\';b='print;p(a%(a,b));';p=\
print;p(a%(a,b));c='c=%r;p(b+c%%c)';p(b+c%c)
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@59oq55oq1pknQQiCmxjYtSBTPWCosy8EusCjURVjUSdJE1Na3WQHBeGcLKtejJYo0aSdrKqarKmOpSZrPn/PwA)

The Levenshtein distance is 38, which is 86.36% of 44.

**Explanation:**

This is similar to the standard quine `s='s=%r;print s%%s';print s%s`. I had to try a lot of combinations and modifications in order to find my program. Creating the function `p` was used to make the second line shorter. The `\` on the end of the first line is a line-continuation character.

#### a

```python
a='a=%r;b=%r;p=\\'
```

- A string template that results in the first line

#### b

```python
b='print;p(a%(a,b));'
```

- String that represents the first part of the 2nd line

#### p

```python
p=\
print
```

- Shorten stuff, change lengths

#### line 1

```python
p(a%(a,b))
```

- Print the first line

#### c

```python
c='c=%r;p(b+c%%c)'
```

- String representing itself plus the part after that prints `b`

#### line 2

```python
p(b+c%c)
```

- Outputs the second line

Comment: Dang. That is impressive, good job!

Comment: If you want to make me smile (I would offer a upvote but you already got it) add a explanation